# Why state dependant on props in child component isn't updated when passed props are changing?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a dynamic form component and I have my Auth component where the state looks like this:

```
  state = {
    signUpMode: true,
    formComponents: {
      email: {
        elements: {
          elementType: "input",
          label: "E-mail",
        },
        configs: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "E-mail",
          value: "",
          name: "email",
        },
        validation: {
          required: true,
        },
        isValid: false,
        error: "",
      },
      password: {
        elements: {
          elementType: "input",
          label: "Password",
        },
        configs: {
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "Password",
          value: "",
          name: "password",
        },
        validation: {
          required: true,
        },
        isValid: false,
        error: "",
      },
      submit: {
        elements: {
          elementType: "input",
        },
        configs: {
          type: "submit",
          value: "Sign Up",
          name: "signup",
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

formComponents holds all the configuration for each input how it should look like and I pass them as props to my Form component

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="auth">
        <Form submitHandler={this.props.Auth} signUp={this.state.signUpMode} formInputs={this.state.formComponents}></Form>
        <button className="switch-auth-mode" onClick={this.switchAuthMode}>
          Switch to {this.state.signUpMode ? "Sign In" : "Sign Up"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Everything is working fine except as you can see I have this button to change to sign up mode or sign in mode which changes the value of the submit element inside the formComponents to Sign Up or Sign In

```
<button className="switch-auth-mode" onClick={this.switchAuthMode}>
```

switchAuthMode changes the signUpMode and as callback is supposed to change the text of the submit and it does

```
switchAuthMode = () => {
    this.setState((prevstate) => {
      return {
        signUpMode: !prevstate.signUpMode,
      };
    }, this.switchButton);
  };
```

I am using lodash clonedeep to clone the formComponents

```
switchButton = () => {
    let formComponents = cloneDeep(this.state.formComponents);

    if (this.state.signUpMode) {
      formComponents.submit.configs.value = "Sign Up";
    } else {
      formComponents.submit.configs.value = "Sign In";
    }
    this.setState({ formComponents });
  };
```

The problem is now on my Form Component when I change that Sign Up or Sign In value in the submit element it doesn't change it stays the initial one, it receives it as props correctly but inside the state doesn't change, in other words the state isn't updating why?

I tried both setting the state in the `componentDidMount()` like this:

```
state = {
    formInputs: {},
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ formInputs: this.props.formInputs }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  }
```

or directly like this:

```
state = {
    formInputs: {...this.props.formInputs},
  };
```

But none is working, what am I doing wrong?

As Zimri Leijen suggested I added

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { if (this.props.signUp !== prevProps.signUp) { this.setState({ formInputs: this.props.formInputs }); } }
```

the problem is now on first click doesn't update but in the second yes and it shows wrong when should be sign up shows sign in and the opposite

Comment: If you log out `this.state.signUpMode` in your `switchButton` method, does it show the updated state? I'm wondering if `this.state` is still referring to the old state.

Comment: @RobertCooper yes it shows correctly because I am using it as a callback after the setState()

Answer (score 0):

the component won't remount every time a prop changes. therefore `componentDidMount()` won't trigger, and your state won't update.

you need a different lifecycle method

in this case `componentDidUpdate()` would be a good fit.

Comment: componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.signUp !== prevProps.signUp) {
      this.setState({ formInputs: this.props.formInputs });
    }
  }

the problem is now on first click doesn't update but in the second yes and it shows wrong when should be  sign up shows sign in and the opposite